# Using subscriber/callback function inside of a class C++

Tags: c++

[image: Rosanswers logo]

For the life of me I cannot seem to figure out why this code is not working and throws up a lot of errors:

```
class Example {

public:

    Example(ros::NodeHandle n )
    {
        sub = n.subscribe("/camera/depth_registered/points", 1000, &this->callBack);

    }

    void callBack(const sensor_msgs::PointCloud2Ptr& msg)
    {


    }

protected:

    ros::Subscriber sub; 
};
```

I have initialised the `ros::Subscriber sub` inside of the class members but cannot seem to figure out why it's giving me an error.

Any ideas?

EDIT:

Here are the error messages:

`error: no matching function for call to ‘ros::NodeHandle::subscribe(const char [32], int, <unresolved overloaded function type>)’ /src/talker.cpp:11:71: note: candidates are: /opt/ros/hydro/include/ros/node_handle.h:379:14: note: template<class M, class T> ros::Subscriber ros::NodeHandle::subscribe(const string&, uint32_t, void (T::*)(M), T*, const ros::TransportHints&)`

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/108551/using-subscriber/callback-function-inside-of-a-class-c++/) by [Phorce](https://answers.ros.org/users/9496/phorce/) on ROS Answers with karma: 97 on 2013-12-09

Post score: 7

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2013-12-09**:
What exact errors? When are you getting them? During compile or when running? Initial guess: Try adding a this to the subscribe call an specify the classname instead of this-> for the subscribe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Callbacks with class member functions are a little tricky. "Regular" functions are merely a pointer to some code in memory. Class member functions have additional state information, namely the object instance they belong to, so you cannot just plug a member function into a regular function pointer and expect it to work.

There are two easy ways to solve this. Firstly, the ROS developers anticipated this problem and provided a neat alternative `subscribe` method that accepts member functions and the corresponding object like this:

`sub = n.subscribe("/camera/depth_registered/points", 1000, &Example::callBack, this);`

The `&Example::callBack` is the function pointer to the member function, and `this` is the object instance for which you want to have the callback called.

But even if they had forgotten, the second option is to use `boost::bind()`, a very powerful tool to bind arguments to arbitrary functions, which supports class member functions as well:

`sub = n.subscribe("/camera/depth_registered/points", 1000, boost::bind(&Example::callBack, this, _1));`

The syntax is slightly more complicated, but it is much more versatile (read the Boost documentation for details).

---

Originally posted by [roehling](https://answers.ros.org/users/798/roehling/) with karma: 1951 on 2013-12-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 32

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [westeast](https://answers.ros.org/users/30354/westeast/) on 2017-05-13**:
I have the same problem , I used the boost::bind,but I have new error information

the code:
_sub_object = _nh.subscribe("/perception/object",1,boost::bind(&MotionCore::_callback_from_perception_obstacle,this));

the error:
In file included from /home/westeast/git/enmodel/src/trajectory/nodes/final

**Comment by [roehling](https://answers.ros.org/users/798/roehling/) on 2018-05-04**:
You forgot the placeholder _1 for the argument that will be passed to your callback

**Comment by [BryceWilley](https://answers.ros.org/users/33606/brycewilley/) on 2018-08-24**:
If using `boost::bind`, the [subscribe docs](http://wiki.ros.org/roscpp/Overview/Publishers%20and%20Subscribers#Functor_Objects) have a useful note not mentioned here: ...

**Comment by [BryceWilley](https://answers.ros.org/users/33606/brycewilley/) on 2018-08-24**:\

> when using functor objects (like boost::bind, for example) you must explicitly specify the message type as a template argument, because the compiler cannot deduce it in this case.

**Comment by [db](https://answers.ros.org/users/31437/db/) on 2020-08-14**:
why was this so hard to find